# knex join returning array on data field used to merge tables in SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, knex.js

When I perform a join with two tables, knex returns an array on column that I use to join tables, like this:

```
{
  user_team_id: 1,
  user_id: 3,
  team_id: [ 2, 2 ],
  is_main: true,
  is_master: false,
  added_at: 2021-01-15T17:09:20.436Z,
  team_name: 'Devs',
  created_at: 2021-01-15T17:07:54.181Z
}
```

My js code:

```
async getUserMainTeam(user_id){
    return knex('core.user_teams as ut')
      .where({user_id: user_id})
      .andWhere({is_main: true})
      .select('*')
      .join('core.teams as t', {'t.team_id': 'ut.team_id'})
      .then(([row]) => row)
  }
```

Comment: it seems strange cause the same code with pgsql does not return this to me.

Comment: Sound like mssql specific behavior. You could try reading node-mssql docs if it says anything about it...